# connection speed and quality of service of hyper-v virtual machines

Tags: linux, windows, hyper-v

I have a Win64-8.1 machine hosting several ArchLinux guests. Both host and guests connect through the same Ethernet adapter via a Virtual Switch.

The connection to the provider, measured by speedtest.net on the host, is >90 Mbit/s download  and >9 Mbit/s upload. The connection from any of the ArchLinux guests, however, is exactly 7 Mbit/s, both down and up.

I conclude that the Hyper-V Virtual Switch is somehow throttling the network connection. How can I tweak the Virtual Switch to ensure QoS on the hosts?

Comment: Care to explain why you voted me down? I could not find any mention of QoS tweaks for the Virtual Switch on google.

Comment: Check that you got the appropriate drivers loaded: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531030.aspx

Comment: Emulated drivers tend to be slow.  I hit the same problem a while back with a virtual Linux instance where the fast network driver was not loaded so the network speed was limited to 3 megabytes per second using a lot of cpu.

Comment: Thank you all. Do you believe that I would see a dramatic improvement if I added a physical network adapter dedicated exclusively to one ArchLinux guest?

Comment: So, I have added a second NIC, which of course is still accessed through the virtual switch. Regrettably, the speed seems to be still capped at 7mbit/sec. @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: can you explain how to load the "fast network driver" in a Hyper-V environment (Win 8.1 64bit)?